# requirejs, datatables and pdfmake - Uncaught File 'Roboto-Regular.ttf' not found in virtual file system

Tags: datatables, requirejs, pdfmake

Here is my code.

```
requirejs.config({
 "paths":{
'pdfmake': '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.min',
},

"shim": {
'pdfmake': {
            deps: ["//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"]
        },
}

});
```

and in datatables - https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/pdfMessage.html

```
requirejs(['pdfmake'],function(){
 $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                messageTop: 'PDF created by PDFMake with Buttons for DataTables.'
            }
        ]
    } );

});
```

in inspect i see files is loaded but when i create pdf - get

```
Uncaught File 'Roboto-Regular.ttf' not found in virtual file system
```

UPDATE 1
i try create live example but have some error ... 
https://jsfiddle.net/9gkat5dc/13/

Failed to load 'https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.4.2/swf/flashExport.swf' as a plugin, because the frame into which the plugin is loading is sandboxed.

Answer (score 0):

```
"shim": {
    "vfs_fonts": ["pdfmake"]
},
```

should solve this (it does in my installation). vfs_fonts needs to load AFTER pdfmake, not before. As far as I understand your config your pdfmake depends on vfs_fonts.

Edit: I see you add the URL to vfs_fonts as dep. I did this in up in the paths-array.